# Finding Eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can I get a comprehensive guide on how to find the eigenvectors for this matrix?

$$ \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        8 & -4 & -4 \\
        -4 & 4 & 0 \\
        -4 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right] $$

I have worked out the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 18,9,9$

Many thanks

Comment: Your eigenvalues are wrong: $\lambda = 4$ should be an eigenvalue

Answer (score 2):

you can call your matrix A, and solve the eigenvalue problem Aψ=λψ by demanding the det(A-λΙ)=0, I is the 3×3 identity matrix. You can verify your answer in mathematica. In every eigenvalue problem when you have the matrix you can find eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Here your eigenvectors will be 3×1 matrixes. Follow the

https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Rozenn.Dahyot/CS1BA1/SolutionEigen.pdf&ved=0CBgQFjAAahUKEwjSgPGcsZjJAhWEiCwKHYouCW0&usg=AFQjCNHpYyOzZbh6Ay-CUenEEMjy2g7wnA

Mathematica Code:
                   A = {{8, -4, -4}, {-4, 4, 0}, {-4, 0, 4}};

```
               Eigenvalues[A]

               {12, 4, 0}
```

So your EigenValues are 
12,4,0

Answer (score 0):

By definition, eigenvectors are the elements in $N(A - \lambda I)$ where $A$ is the matrix in question, $I$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate size, and $N$ denotes the nullspace (recall that a vector $v \in N(A)$ if $Av = 0$.) So when you are asked to identify eigenvectors, you should present it in basis form.

As for actually computing it, you should first fix an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and then explicitly compute $A- \lambda I$ to get a new matrix. At this point, the problem of eigenvectors is equivalent to computing the nullspace of this new matrix.